# Arithmetic Progressions with a Finite Number of Primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

Is there an arithmetic progression that includes {1} that also includes only a finite number of prime numbers? Or will all progressions including {1} have infinite primes?

Comment: Maybe it would help if I said why I was asking this. I'm trying to show that the set of integers Z is not compact under the arithmetic progression topology. So I have the collection of progressions {0+kp} where k is an integer and p is prime. The union of those progressions covers Z\{-1,1}. So I only need a progression with 1 and a progression with -1 to cover Z. But since 1 is coprime with all integers, the Dirichlet Theorem says those progressions will contain infinitely many integers. That opens up the possibility of finite sub-collections covering Z, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Are you trying to recreate Furstenburg's (sp?) proof?

Comment: @abiessu no, but the concept is related.

Comment: By "a finite sub-collection covering $\Bbb Z$", do you mean something like $\{2a\},\{3a\},\{6a-1\},\{6a+1\}$?

Comment: @abiessu a finite collection of progressions, yeah

Comment: @user324636: Instead of working with different primes, you can partition $\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ according to the highest power of $2$ that divides each number. Each equivalence class turns out to be an arithmetic progression, and there's an infinity of them. Then take, for example, $3\mathbb Z$ to cover $0$ too; that intersects each of the other progressions but does not contain any of them.

Comment: Consider http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1504635/86846 for more information.

Answer (score 3):

[Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) says (among other cases) that every integer arithmetic progression that starts at $1$ contains infinitely many primes.